# synchronized(self): how to avoid self being destroyed whilst waiting for the lock

Tags: objective-c

Consider the following:

```
@protocol P
   -(void)doSomething
@end

@implementation foo <P>
{
    bar b;
}

-(void) init
{
    [b setDelegate: self];
}

-(void)doSomething
{
    synchronized(self)
    {
        ... do stuff with properties of self ...
    }
}

-(void)doSomethingElse
{
    synchronized(self)
    {
        ... do other stuff with properties of self ...
    }
}

-(void)dealloc()
{
    synchronized(self)
    {
       b.delegate = nil;
       ... destroy properties of self ...
    }
}

@end
```

In a multi-threaded situation.. how is it possible to prevent foo.doSomething being called whilst dealloc is acquiring the lock ??

The sequence I think I'm seeing is:

- Thread-1: enter dealloc
- Thread-2: enter doSomething
- Thread-1: acquire lock on self
- Thread-2: wait on lock on self
- Thread-1: release lock on self
- Thread-2: acquire lock on self
- Thread-1: destroy self
- Thread-2: -- BOOM -- [foo release called on deallocated instance] as it attempts to release the lock

Since bar, as seems usual, holds a weak reference to it's delegate (and bar is a foreign class BTW, so I can't change this) it seems impossible to safely dealloc an instance of foo when bar may call it's delegate at any time.

I'd appreciate some insight here, this must be a standard problem but I haven't seen much discussion about it here or elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure bar has weak reference to foo? It sounds like unsafe_unretained to me. Also could you try moving `b.delegate = nil` outside of synchronized block in `deinit`.

Comment: If it helps any bar is NSInputStream in my case and the delegate is @property(assign). I did give some thought to moving b.delegate = nil outside the lock, will give it a go and get back to you.

Comment: Please note that `assign` is not equal to `weak`. `Weak` references are automatically set to nil, when pointed object is released from the memory, whereas `assign` aren't, and they start pointing to memory which is now used for someone else(hence garbage).

Answer (score 0):

There are similar patterns and problems when using KVO or notifications from multiple threads.  It seems like per-object serial queues give you better control than `synchronized` for handling this.

You can create a `NSOperationQueue` with a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of one.  That provides synchronization.  `dealloc` can prevent the problem of waiting tasks behind it by suspending the queue and cancelling waiting tasks.